# Yii2: How to implement social login using facebook, twitter, google & linkedin

Tags: yii2

Anyone practically knows how to implement social login in website. Any method is preferred any Hauth or oauth or o2auth. I want to know how to implement using yii2 framework...

Answer (score 6):

I think you need openId, try this, may help you

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-authclient

Comment: My preferred way to go with is h-auth. If not then for oauth.